# How to add a watermark with Yii2 kartik-mpdf

Tags: php, yii2, mpdf

How can I add watermark image on pdf using kartik-pdf?

Here is the line I added:

```
'options' => [
    'title' => 'Title',
    'showWatermarkText' => true,
    'showWatermarkImage' => true,
],
// call mPDF methods on the fly
'methods' => [ 
    'SetHeader' => ['Title'], 
    'SetFooter' => ['{PAGENO}'],
    'SetWatermarkText' => ['DRAFT'],
    'SetWatermarkImage' => $basepath . '/images/imgbox1.jpg',
]
```

Only the text watermark display.

Is there something wrong on how I used watermarkImage?

Comment: I encountered a similar problem but I realized that it was something to do with the file path for the image. I wrote the path in full `'frontend/img/bgimage.jpg'` and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

use kartik mpdf library to create object of mpdf;
The following code will create simple pdf using kartik widget

```
use mPDF;
class SiteController extends Controller
{
public funtion createpdf() 
{
    $HTML='your html content';
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(); //please use your kartik mpdf object here 
    $mpdf->SetWatermarkImage('../images/background.jpg');
    $mpdf->showWatermarkImage = true;

    $mpdf->WriteHTML($HTML);
   // Saves file on the server as 'filename.pdf'
   $mpdf->Output('filename.pdf', \Mpdf\Output\Destination::FILE);
}
}
```

Comment: can you give me a little example. I didn't get what you mean. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't just dump code, include an explanation

Comment: it say's headers already sent when i use:
`$mpdf->Output('filename.pdf', 'I');`

Comment: check anything printing before calling pdf function.

Comment: I'd print line after line. and the `$mpdf->Output('filename.pdf', \Mpdf\Output\Destination::INLINE)` I think is the error.

Answer (score 0):

Set the SetWatermarkImage property as an array, like this:

```
// call mPDF methods on the fly
'methods' => [ 
    'SetHeader' => ['Title'], 
    'SetFooter' => ['{PAGENO}'],
    'SetWatermarkText' => ['DRAFT'],
    'SetWatermarkImage' => ['/images/imgbox1.jpg'],
]
```

Also, you have to check the image path. You used the `$basepath`, I usually don't use it, since my `images` folder is already inside my `web` folder.